# How to establish database connection on startup using Panache Reactive

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-panache

I have a simple application using:

- Quarkus 3.1.2.Final
- Hibernate Reactive with Panache extension
- Reactive PostgreSQL client
- RestEasy Reactive extension

The `appilcation.yml` is:

```yaml
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: postgresql
    username: qs-bench
    password: qs-bench
    reactive:
      name: ds-pool
      url: vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost:5431/qs-bench
      reconnect-attempts: 1
  hibernate-orm:
    log:
      format-sql: true
      sql: true
```

**Important**: The port number is wrong on purpose, PostgreSQL server is listening on port 5432.

The application starts normally (there is no success or error message in logs)

```
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2023-06-24 22:19:34,379 INFO  [org.hib.rea.pro.imp.ReactiveIntegrator] (JPA Startup Thread) HR000001: Hibernate Reactive
2023-06-24 22:19:34,737 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) bookstore-quarkus-reactive 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.1.2.Final) started in 1.657s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2023-06-24 22:19:34,742 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
2023-06-24 22:19:34,743 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, config-yaml, hibernate-orm, hibernate-reactive, hibernate-reactive-panache, hibernate-validator, reactive-pg-client, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi, vertx]
```

I expect the database connection should be established during startup and the application shouldn't start if it failed.

Is there any solution that answer my expectations?

When I call any REST endpoint which turns to Panache Repository like:

```bash
curl -v http://localhost:8080/books
```

I got an error response:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /books HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 72
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"details":"Error id 80489e7f-1c45-427d-92b4-ab72a998e5f5-1","stack":""}
```

In `prod` mode there is no other information neither in response body nor in the logs.

However, in `dev` mode I got more detailed response, nothing was logged even the error message or stacktrace.

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /books HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 1395
< 
{"details":"Error id fdabe0fa-731d-4cb1-b65c-4d807e7363ab-1, io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:5431","stack":"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:5431\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)\n\tat io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)\n\tat io.netty.channel* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)"}
```

When the `health` endpoint called I got confusing `DOWN` respose

```json
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "checks": [
        {
            "name": "Reactive PostgreSQL connections health check",
            "status": "DOWN",
            "data": {
                "<default>": "UP"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

because the response states `<default>` datasource is up, but fortunately at least the health service logs the error:

```
2023-06-24 22:56:52,748 WARN  [io.qua.rea.dat.run.ReactiveDatasourceHealthCheck] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-12) 
Error obtaining database connection for healthcheck of datasource '<default>': io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:5431
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I also made this demo using imperative / classic Hibernate, Pahache and RestEasy extensions and that works as I expected, trying to connect at application startup and throw (and log) the exception.

Additionally here is the full `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.zforgo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore-quarkus-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.1.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>

        <hypersistence-utils.version>3.4.3</hypersistence-utils.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                </native.image.path>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a bug. [I've created an issue to improve the error message](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34301).

If you set the property:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=validate
```

Quarkus will execute the validation of the database at start up and throw the following error message:

```
2023-06-26 10:01:51,741 INFO  [org.hib.rea.pro.imp.ReactiveIntegrator] (JPA Startup Thread) HR000001: Hibernate Reactive                                                                                              
2023-06-26 10:01:52,419 ERROR [org.hib.rea.errors] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HR000057: Failed to execute statement [select * from information_schema.sequences]: could not execute query : java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:5432
```

By the way, Quarkus doesn't start Hibernate Reactive at start up, because the idea is to make it possible to start different services in parallel. Otherwise, you could have a situation where a request happens before the database is ready.